# how to automatically combine user model to a custom user model

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

i have this custom user model

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

and i use allauth package for authentication and once i sign up a new user i got this error in the main page of the website:
**RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /
User has no customer.**

is there a way to combine the user to a customer automatically once the user got created?

Answer (score 0):

You can override save() method of you user creation form and include creation of the Customer there:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email']

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(UserRegisterForm, self).save(commit=False)
        if commit:
            user.save()
            Customer.objects.create(user=user, name=user.username, email=user.email)
        return user
```

Comment: Could you please show your view and template where you create user.

Answer (score 0):

i figured it out

first import post_save and receiver

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
```

then

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s's profile" % self.user


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_customer(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        cuatomer, created = Customer.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)


post_save.connect(create_user_customer, sender=User)
```

at settings.py

```
AUTH_USER_MODULE = 'YOURAPP.Customer'
```